# Range bar Chart in SSRS - How to display both Start and End label?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am using Range Bar chart in SSRS 2008. I am able to show the label for each bar, but i need to display both the start and end point label for each bar.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Series area, right click on the series and select "Show Data Labels".  Pops them right up!